# SSRS Sorting and Renaming an Empty String

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm building a bar chart that has many values and one of the values is an empty string.  When added in SSRS, the blank string returns a '1' value (**The first bar on the chart**).  How do I change the name from '1' to Blank?  Also, how do I sort an Blank string within the chart?

[image]

Here's what I tried on changing the name to 'Blank' and it doesn't seem seems to be working:

```
=iif (IsNothing(Fields!AGE.Value), "Blank", iif(CSTR(Fields!AGE.Value)= "", "Blank", CStr(Fields!AGE.Value)
```

Here's what I tried to sort and can't get it to work..probably because to empty string is messing me up.  I'm only showing a sample below otherwise the code would be too long.

```
=Switch(Fields!Age.value="INCORRECT", 1, Fields!Age.value= "AO", 2,true,3)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: why don't you try to update it from dataset (Inside sql query) - if you don't want to do that then try this, `=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!AGE.Value)=1 OR Fields!AGE.Value=1,"Blank",IIF(CStr(Fields!AGE.Value)= "", "Blank", CStr(Fields!AGE.Value)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@rajeshpanchal - thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  I went back and changed my SQL query to include the empty strings within the Case statement.  Something like `Case when fieldname = '10' and fieldname = '' then 'Blank Profile'`

Once I had the empty string named to something other than '1', then I was able to sort my chart within SSRS by creating a new calculated field and using the following Switch function:

```
=Switch(Fields!Age.value="INCORRECT", 1, Fields!Age.value= "AO", 2,true,3)
```

I then went to the chart data, right clicked on the category group and choose category group properties..then clicked on sorting and input my newly created sorting field.  I was trying to get the INCORRECT bar to show first on the chart and you can see below that it worked.

[image]